# Flutter - Get SHA-1 Certificate - Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, flutter, sha1

I'm trying to retrieve the SHA-1 Fingerprint Certificate for my Flutter Project. This can usually be done going into the Gradle Panel on the right side in Android Studio and clicking on `signingReport`.

The problem is however, in Flutter, it doesn't show the Gradle Panel at all and after an hour of searching, I still couldn't find a way to get that panel to show.

I tried the Keytool way, but it tells me there's no such command in the Command Prompt. How do I get the SHA-1 Certificate for my flutter project? I need it for signing in my Flutter Project with Firebase Auth.

I've also searched in the Firebase Documentation, there is no documentation of how to find the SHA-1 in flutter. It simply says that SHA-1 is required for using Firebase Auth.

Related issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24776

Comment: Have you tried opening the `android/` directory in Android Studio and checked if the menu is available then?

Comment: @Günter Yes I have. I even opened one of the `build.gradle` files.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem, to get the SHA-1 there are two ways:

1. Using Keytool (didn't work with me)
2. Using Gradle's Signing Report , which I used ,**FIrst** on terminal go to android folder with command:

```
cd android
```

and the following command to get the report:

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

then it will show the `signingReport` which you can retrieve the SHA-1 from it.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks! Your answer worked. It doesn't require the `chmod` command. Directly doing `./gradlew signingReport` when in the `/android` directory of the Flutter Project will work.

Comment: Thank for the neat and clean answer, it works like charm

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying that the following option (view Gradle panel) is not at all available?

[image: gradle enable]

Comment: Not in my flutter project, no. Do you have a flutter project on or a regular Android project? Because I can't see any flutter options in that menu, which would normally be there when working on a flutter project.

Answer (score 1):

[Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) documents how to obtain your SHA-1 with `keytool`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command from [Authenticating Your Client](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) with Command Prompt:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

If the command doesn't work, then include the path to `keytool.exe`. For me, that was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\keytool.exe`. So the command I used was as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this command below if you are using **Windows OS**. Make sure to replace the ***username*** within the path with your username where android studio is installed. You could easily replace the ***C:\Users\username*** with the path of your user account where Android studio is installed.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```