# Missing keystore - Can't get SHA1

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I try to get SHA1 to use for Firebase but I can't get SHA1

In **JavaVirtualMachines** I using **jdk1.8.0_202.jdk**

1. I tried get in gradle -> Task -> Android -> signingReport

=> Error: Missing keystore

2. I tried get on command line ->

> keytool  -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
> ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v

> keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/bobhope/.android/debug.keystore      -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

=> Error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/bobhope/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/bobhope/.android/debug.keystore
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:786)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:382)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:375)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63796336/18585332

Comment: see above the link follow steps then you will get the sha key

Comment: mention the MacOs in the question title bro

Comment: which  editer r u using

Answer (score 4):

Use complete path

> Mac:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

> Linux:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/username/.android/debug.keystore
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

> Windows:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore
-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: It not work with me

Comment: Still error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/bobhope/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/bobhope/.android/debug.keystore
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:786)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:382)
    at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:375)

Comment: did u try @Kumaresan Jackie answerr

Comment: which os u r using ?

Comment: macOS Monterey version 12.3.1

Comment: I tried Jackie answer

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244493/discussion-between-anandh-krishnan-and-bob-le).

Answer (score 0):

you missed the path in your command

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

after the `keystore` you should add the path like `C:\Users\Username\Downloads`

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. **Clean and rebuild your application.**
2. Open the Gradle tab and go to **app -> Tasks -> android**
3. Double click on **signingReport**.

[image]

4. You will get the required signing report below in the run tab.

[image]